# Get the MAX datetime value from the MIN date

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has a part number, part serial number, part test number, part test result and date part tested. The keys are part number, part serial number, part test number and date part tested. A part is tested with the same serial number and the test number in different days and different time in same day. I want to see the first day it was tested and last result of that day. I want to create a view. There can be different part number and each part number can have different serial numbers. each part number is associated with different test numbers

Below is the results for a particular part number, serial #, test

```
part number serial number   TEST #       DATE   test-value
555-99          abcd123         10  11/30/18 2:02   0
555-99          abcd123         10  11/30/18 2:22   13714.66797
555-99          abcd123         10  11/30/18 2:23   2
555-99          abcd123         10  11/30/18 9:22   5
555-99          abcd123         10  11/30/18 10:22  14809.70703
555-99          abcd123         10  1/9/19 6:13 14574.62891
555-99          abcd123         10  1/9/19 6:14 14084.62891
555-99          abcd123         10  1/9/19 14:53    14119.66797
555-99          abcd123         10  1/9/19 14:54    13874.72656
555-99          abcd123         10  1/9/19 14:53    14844.74609
555-99          abcd123         10  1/11/19 7:19    15404.76563
555-99          abcd123         10  1/15/19 17:47   14179.76563
555-99          abcd123         10  1/17/19 0:17    14214.64844
555-99          abcd123         10  1/17/19 0:17    14216.64944
```

Output should be

```
555-99  abcd123 10  11/30/18 9:22   5
```

I want to create a view that has all part numbers with each serial number and their test number with last time when it was first tested.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This give the desired result if i pass the serial number:

```html
 DECLARE @DATE DATETIME2(7);
   DECLARE @TOPDATE DATETIME2(7);
   DECLARE @MAXDATE DATETIME2(7);
    SELECT @Date = MIN(DATA_Date_Time) FROM DATA_Fields WHERE DATA_Serial = 
    'UNLDR598' ;
    SELECT @TOPDATE   = dateadd(hh,  23,  @DATE)
    select  @MAXDATE  =max(DATA_Date_Time )from DATA_Fields where  
    DATA_Date_Time    >   @DATE AND     DATA_Date_Time    <  @TOPDATE  AND 
    DATA_Serial = 'UNLDR598'  
     SELECT  DATA_PART,DATA_SERIAL, DATA_TEST,  data_value ,DATA_Date_Time 
     FROM DATA_Fields
  
       where DATA_Serial = 'UNLDR598' 
       AND   DATA_Date_Time = @MAXDATE 


 <br>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the last time and day it was tested be...  1/17/19 0:17? Or am I missing something.

Comment: The way I understood the question is: They are looking for the last time of the first day it was tested. So you would need to find the date for the first day it was tested and then find the last test for that date.

Comment: In that case wouldn't `11/30/18 10:22 ` be the last test of that date and not `11/30/18 9:22`. Hence my confusion as it is slightly unclear.

Comment: @arahman Fair enough, I didn't look that closely as to see that. The question is worded in a confusing way.

Comment: @NickA I agree, that is what confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script, which will do the trick. It is not so elegant, but should work faster.

```
SELECT yt.*
FROM #YourTable AS yt
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT md = MIN(CAST(i.[DATE] AS date)) FROM #YourTable AS i
    WHERE i.[part number] = yt.[part number]
        AND i.[serial number] = yt.[serial number]
        AND i.[TEST #] = yt.[TEST #]
) AS MinDate
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MT = MAX(i.[DATE]) FROM #YourTable AS i
    WHERE i.[part number] = yt.[part number]
        AND i.[serial number] = yt.[serial number]
        AND i.[TEST #] = yt.[TEST #]
        AND CAST(i.[DATE] AS date) = MinDate.MD
) AS MaxTime
WHERE yt.DATE = MaxTime.MT
```

Comment: BTW. There might be a problem, if there is more than one record with "the last time of the first day"

Comment: The query gave me the result of the last value of the first day but it also gave me the all the results of the other days. Is there any way we can fix it? Thanks a ton

Comment: made some modification. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use two window functions to achieve this.

```
declare @table table ([part number] varchar(6), [serial number] varchar(16),   [TEST #] int,  [DATE] datetime,  [test-value] decimal(10,5))
insert into @table
values
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 2:02',0),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 2:22',13714.66797),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 2:23',2),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 9:22',5),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 10:22',14809.70703),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 6:13',14574.62891),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 6:14',14084.62891),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 14:53',14119.66797),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 14:54',13874.72656),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 14:53',14844.74609),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/11/19 7:19',15404.76563),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/15/19 17:47',14179.76563),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/17/19 0:17',14214.64844),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/17/19 0:17',14216.64944)

select top 1 with ties * 
from
(
    select 
        *
        ,FirstDay = dense_rank() over (partition by [part number], [serial number], [TEST #] order by cast([DATE] as date))
    from @table
) x
where FirstDay = 1
order by row_number() over (partition by [part number], [serial number], [TEST #] order by [DATE] desc)
```

Thais answers the request *I want to see the first day it was tested and last result of that day* which **does not match** your sample output.

To get the *next to last* which is what your expected output has, use something like:

```
select * 
from(
    select 
        *
        ,RN = row_number() over (partition by [part number], [serial number], [TEST #] order by [DATE] desc)
    from
        (
        select 
            *
            ,FirstDay = dense_rank() over (partition by [part number], [serial number], [TEST #] order by cast([DATE] as date))
        from @table
        ) x
    where FirstDay = 1
) y
where RN = 2
```

Comment: Just curious would that give you the output given in the question above or does it give you the row where date is: `11/30/18 10:22 `. 5th row in that sample table.

Comment: Not the output requested but answers the question, which as you both stated was contradicting @arahman But i provided a solution for that as well.

Comment: I thought as much, that it would not be the same output as what the OP had shown in his answer.

Comment: well i added a fix for that, but they probably just goofed up the question @arahman

Comment: Well, I Plugged the query .This is the query  : <br>select top 1 with ties * 
from
(
    select 
        *
        ,[DATA_Date_Time] = dense_rank() over (partition by [DATA_Part], [DATA_Serial],[DATA_Test]  order by cast([DATA_Date_Time] as date))
    from DATA_Fields
) x
where DATA_Date_Time= 1
order by row_number() over (partition by [DATA_Part], [DATA_Serial],[DATA_Test]  order by [DATA_Date_Time] desc) <br> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The column 'DATA_Date_Time' was specified multiple times for 'x'.

Comment: Hard for me to read that unformatted but my code works so all you should have to do is change the table name @tresaa

Answer (score 0):

Just for funzies I did it with common table expressions. In theory this should work to find last time of the first date of all combinations of Part and serial number for every test number.

Base Data(Thanks @scsimon for the code on this):

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable (part_number varchar(10), serial_number varchar(20), TESTnum int,  Tdate datetime,  Test_Value decimal(10,5))
insert into #TestTable
values
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 2:02',0),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 2:22',13714.66797),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 2:23',2),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 9:22',5),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'11/30/18 10:22',14809.70703),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 6:13',14574.62891),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 6:14',14084.62891),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 14:53',14119.66797),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 14:54',13874.72656),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/9/19 14:53',14844.74609),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/11/19 7:19',15404.76563),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/15/19 17:47',14179.76563),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/17/19 0:17',14214.64844),
('555-99','abcd123',10,'1/17/19 0:17',14216.64944)
```

Then I did it using CTEs. First I found the min date, then the max time then put it all together:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT tt.part_number
           ,tt.serial_number
           ,tt.TESTnum
           ,MIN(CAST(tt.Tdate as DATE)) AS MinDate
     FROM #TestTable tt
     GROUP BY tt.part_number, tt.serial_number, tt.TESTnum),

     CTE1 AS
     (SELECT tt.part_number
            ,tt.serial_number
            ,tt.TESTnum
            ,MAX(tt.Tdate) AS Date1
      FROM #TestTable tt 
      JOIN CTE c ON tt.part_number = c.part_number
             AND tt.serial_number = c.serial_number
             AND tt.TESTnum = c.TESTnum
      WHERE c.MinDate = CAST(tt.Tdate as DATE)
      GROUP BY tt.part_number, tt.serial_number, tt.TESTnum)

SELECT   t.part_number
        ,t.serial_number
        ,t.TESTnum
        ,T.Tdate
        ,t.Test_Value
FROM #TestTable t
JOIN cte1 c ON t.part_number = c.part_number
            AND t.serial_number = c.serial_number
            AND t.TESTnum = c.TESTnum
WHERE Tdate = c.date1
```

Comment: Instead of having max of the min day, how will i get the same info with min time plus eight hours. In other words, currently we are selecting max of the minium day but if i want the value after right hours of the minium time.